# Collecting Data from Database, functions vs classes

Tags: python, mysql, database, class, oop

I searched around and couldn't really find any information on this. Basically i have a database "A" and a database "B". What i want to do is create a python script (that will likely run as a cron job) that will collect data from database "A" via sql, perform an action on it, and then input that data into database "B".

I have written it using functions something along the lines of:

- Function 1 gets the date the script was last run
- Function 2 Gets the data from Database "A" based on function 1
- Function 3-5 Perform the needed actions
- Function 6 Inserts data into Database "B"

My question is, it was mentioned to me that i should use a Class to do this rather than just functions. The only problem is, I am honestly a bit hazy on Classes and when to use them.

Would a Class be better for this? Or is writing this out as functions that feed into each other better? If i would use a Class, could you tell me how it would look?

Answer (score 4):

> Would a Class be better for this?

Probably not.

Classes are useful when you have multiple, stateful instances that have shared methods.  Nothing in your problem description matches those criteria.

There's nothing wrong with having a script with a handful of functions to perform simple data transfers (extract, transform, store).

Comment: So in that case, what sort of situation would i want to use a class?

Comment: As I said, if you have multiple instances (with distinct data) and shared functionality (methods), then classes are nice.   Classes can help organize big groups of code.  For short scripts like yours, it likely will add unnecessary overhead.